# Why is this test passing when it shouldnt'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

So I have the following test:

```
it "should not update a user based on invalid info" do
    put :update, :id => @factory.id, :user => {
       :name => '', :user_name => '',
       :email => '', :email_confirmation => '',
       :password => '', :password_confirmation => 'dfgdfgdfg',
       :bio => '', :picture_url => ''
    }
end
```

Which clearly has missing data.

I then have the following controller:

```
  def update
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attributes(user_update_params)
    if @user.save
      render :show
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

This has the following private method:

```
  def user_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :user_name, :email, :email_confirmation, :password,
      :password_confirmation, :bio, :picture_url)
  end
```

When this test is run it passes - it should give me a `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid`

If your interested this is the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password

  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates :name, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  validates :user_name, uniqueness: true, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
  validates :email, presence: true, confirmation: true, uniqueness: true, email_format: {message: "what is this? it's not an email"}
  validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: true, length: {minimum: 10}

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :history]

  def self.authenticate(user_name, password)
    user = User.find_by(user_name: user_name)
    if(user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.salt))
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt)
    end
  end
end
```

I also bet its something very trivial

**Update** Incase your interested this is my factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, :class => 'User' do
    name "sample_user"
    email "MyString@gmail.com"
    user_name "MyString"
    password "someSimpleP{ass}"
  end
end
```

so `@factory` is created from `@factory = FactoryGirl.create(:user)`

Comment: What's the expectation part of the test?  The code you posted is missing that part.  e.g. `response.should_not be_valid`

Comment: Looks like you have missed your expectation. Probably, expect(response).to render_template('edit') since it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're executing an RSpec method (`put`) that will not raise an error as long as the arguments are properly formed so that the message can be sent to the server. Since there was nothing wrong with your arguments per se, no error was raised. Any inability of the *server* to successfully complete the request will be reflect in the response, which you would need to test separately.

Of course, as others have pointed out, it's typical in an RSpec example to set "expectations" on your code which will determine whether the example succeeds or not, so that more than just the absence of an uncaught error will determine success.

Answer (score 0):

Its not like that the test is not passing, but there is no test. You missed the expectation in your test.
Try something like this.

```
it "should not update a user based on invalid info" do
    put :update, :id => @factory.id, :user => {
       :name => '', :user_name => '',
       :email => '', :email_confirmation => '',
       :password => '', :password_confirmation => 'dfgdfgdfg',
       :bio => '', :picture_url => ''
    }
    #add expectation here
    response.should_not be_valid
end
```

Any test without expectation would pass.

Comment: While that's true, the OP meant "passes" in the sense of "not raising an error". In particular, the OP is asking why `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` is not being raised.

Comment: Nothing there would raise that exception. `update_attributes` will either return true or false.

Comment: Your code throws a no method error on valid? I used expect_response().to render()